# Have multiple edit forms. Need to modify update method and routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a User model with name, email, password, and bio.

I want to have two kinds of edit forms. One for editing email, bio and the other for just password.

So my question is really two parts.

A) If the `update_attributes` fails in update method, how to render the correct page, instead of just `edit`. This is my current update method.

```
def update
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
    sign_in @user
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

B) How do I have route like `/users/1/edit` for change_password method? So I want something like `/users/1/change_password`.

---

B) `match '/users/:id/change_password', to: 'users#change_password'` did the job.

Comment: What's the "correct page"? What do you want it to render?

Comment: Either 'edit' or 'change_password' based on which parameters are being updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)`

Should work.

Also I would change your change_password routes to be like this:

```
resource :users do
  member do
    put 'change_password'
  end
end
```

Which is a more Rails-y way of doing things. Then, you can do

`redirect_to change_password_user_path(@user)`

Comment: Thanks. How do you change the `if` statements in the update method to differentiate the cases between `redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)` and `redirect_to change_password_user_path(@user)`?

Comment: `change_password_user_path(@user)` resulted in undefined_method error. So I tried `change_password_users_path(@user)`. It generated wrong route. `http://localhost:3000/users/change_password.1`

Comment: You'd also have to specify the correct CRUD action. If `change_password` is just supposed to render a form, you can change the `put` to `get` in the routes specified above.